# Blank LatexPDF File issue with custom Latex Style with SPHINX

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, pdflatex

Recently I've created my PDF file correctly as in style formatting.

But now I've got the issue that my RST files from Sphinx are not included.

Maybe that someone knows how I include the RST content into the custom ***PREAMBLE*** - **sty** file content

**main.sty**

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,pxfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{32}{$\ $}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\geometry{left=0.2in, top=0.5in, paperwidth=595pt, paperheight=878pt}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{color_93343}{rgb}{0.25098,0.25098,0.25098}
\definecolor{color_217206}{rgb}{0.737255,0.839216,0.443137}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]\path(0pt,0pt);\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(-15,-837.4999){\includegraphics[width=596.25pt,height=887.25pt]{latexImage_ab7aceb12f4add82da5ce423202fd278.png}}
\put(55.775,-99.78003){\fontsize{11}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_93343} }
\put(55.525,-810){\fontsize{11}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_93343} }
\put(282.38,-810){\fontsize{11}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_93343} }
\put(509.48,-810){\fontsize{11}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_93343} }
\put(55.775,-823.5){\fontsize{11}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_93343} }
\put(55.775,-118.05){\fontsize{16}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{color_217206} }
\put(55.775,-150.3){\fontsize{16}{1}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{color_217206} }
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

**[SPHINX] Conf.py:**

```
latex_engine = 'pdflatex'

latex_additional_files = [
    'latexImage_ab7aceb12f4add82da5ce423202fd278.png',
    'main.sty'
]

latex_elements = {
    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    'extraclassoptions': 'openany',
    'preamble' : r"""

        \usepackage{main}

        
        \renewcommand{\subtitle}{%s}

    """ % (project)
}
```

It creates the latex PDF with the correct custom styling.. But all the RST content is not included.

I also tried it with **'latex_documents'** Creation method within the conf.py but resulted also with a blanko PDF file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear how to reproduce the problem (please read [mcve]). I don't understand what you mean by "include the RST content into the custom PREAMBLE".

Comment: I'm not a sphinx user , but if you already have `\begin{document}...\end{document}` in your preamble it won't ever get to your actual document because latex will ignore everything which comes after the end of the document.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your  main package? Add an image to your document? It seems a bit strange to first have an empty tikz picture followed by a picture environment which has a tons of colour and font commands but does not actually add anything but a picture.